# Can I use Newton's method to obtain smallest positive real solution of a quartic?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, quartics

I am familiar with Newton's method, but I'm not sure what convergence guarantees there are for this situation:

I have a quartic in real coefficients $Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E = 0$, and I need to obtain the smallest positive real-valued solution.

Is Newton's method guaranteed to find the smallest positive real solution, if it's set up correctly? Is a starting guess of zero sufficient? Should I be using another method?

Comment: With starting guess zero you could get to a negative solution if it's smaller in absolute value, than the positive one you want

Comment: I can determine prior to this stage that there will be no negative solutions. Then will it work?

Comment: So you want your algorithm to return the smallest positive root for any quartic?

Comment: In case there's no negative roots, I believe the first guess zero should be fine, unless the polynomial has an extremum there (if D=0), then the derivative will be zero and you will not be able to move to the next step.

Comment: I'm skeptical, intuitively it seems that an approximation could overshoot the smallest solution and land close to another, higher solution. Can I avoid this with Newton's?

Comment: good question, I don't know. You should search the literature on the topic. I doubt you could avoid missing the root in the general case. The only sure way to me seems to find all the roots and sort them. There are algorithms to find all the roots for a given polynomial

Answer (score 0):

If you look for the smallest positive zero of equation $$f(x)=Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E $$
$$f'(x)=4Ax^3+3B x^2+2Cx+D$$
$$f''(x)=12A x^2+6Bx+2C$$ by Darboux-Fourier theorem, you will not have any overshoot of the solution  **if and only if**
$$f(x_0)\times f''(x_0) >0$$ For your case, using $x_0=0$, this would imply $CE >0$.